# Lightbox showing only the 1st of the pictures

Tags: javascript, image, load, lightbox, thumbnails

I have a main image which is loaded each time with a different image if you rollover the thumbnail. There are 3 thumbnails.

There is also a lightbox effect and here is where my issue happens. Every time I click on the main image, no matter which of the thumbs has been loaded to the main image, image 1 is the one shown in the lightbox.

I clearly see where the issue is, but I am just wondering how I could make it so the image loaded in the mainImage container is the one shown in the lightbox.

Here is my code, maybe it explains better.

Thanks!

```
<div id="thumbs">
<img class="thumbSelected" src="images/<?php echo $row[thumb1]; ?>.jpg"  /><br />
<img src="images/<?php echo $row[thumb2]; ?>.jpg"  /><br />
<img src="images/<?php echo $row[thumb3]; ?>.jpg"  />
</div>



<div class="mainImage">
<a href="images/<?php echo $row[image1]; ?>.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="<?php echo $row[name]; ?>">
<img class="mainImage" src="images/<?php echo $row[image1]; ?>.jpg" />
</a>
</div>
<script> ////large: ITEM1_01_large      small: ITEM1_01_thumb
//
$('#thumbs').delegate('img', {
mouseover: function(){
    $('.mainImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','image'));
    var $this = $(this),
    index = $this.index();
    $("#thumbs img").removeClass('thumbSelected');
        $this.addClass('thumbSelected');
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
}});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see what you are doing.  However, if jQuery finds the first element and stop if you are using id selector.  **If you want to select multiple elements, you need to use class.**  That's what class is for.

Comment: How could I do it with class? The problem is that the script just applies on the 1st image, not in the others... Should I loop?

Comment: Well, that's why I say I can't really see what you are doing.  But I see `$("#thumbs img")` Do you have a lot of imgs in one div that has an id of "thumbs"?  or you have multiple divs with ids all named "thumbs"?

Comment: ok, I reevaluated your code.  There are better ways to write your php and jQuery.  You can google and follow some lightbox examples.  But it looks like you only loaded image1 for your lightbox.  PHP only execute once per page load, unless you use AJAX.  Also, it's considered bad practice to use $ in the beginning of your regular javascript variable.  It's extremely confusing, considering you are using jQuery _and_ php.